# Keeping a log/table of changes based on changes made in one sheet in Excel

Tags: vba, excel

so my goal is to have one sheet in Excel where a user will input the current month and year, then put in certain information, let's call it "X", "Y", and "Z".
On another sheet, I want this information to update a table that has 12 rows (one for each month) and 3 columns, one for each variable X, Y, and Z.  I only want the data updated for the current month the user input.

What would then happen is the file is saved, and then next month, this file is opened again, and new numbers are put in for X, Y, and Z, as well as a new current month and year, but the problem is:
How can the previous numbers be permanently saved?

I imagine VBA is needed here, as my attempts at using regular Excel functions have not been very successful.  Any help would be appreciated!

EDIT: The attached picture is how I want the Sheet to work, is that possible?
I want to try to make it sort of user error proof if possible too, as in: With track changes, is there a way to only keep the most recent changes made per date?

Comment: How many rows does the user input each month? What kind of update is happening in other sheet with 12 rows? Is is the latest set of values for a given month, the sum of all values for a given month etc?

Comment: If using 2016 have you tried using a data form http://www.dummies.com/software/microsoft-office/excel/how-to-add-records-to-a-data-list-in-excel-2016/    This could be combined with a field that has the NOW function populating it with a DATETIME of data entry. The user would be entering data into a form rather than directly into the sheet. Similar functionality could be achieved with a Userform. There are lots of easy to find links and videos on how to create these.

Comment: use another worksheet that would be used as an electronic journal. .... start at top and each time a user enters data, the values of X,Y,Z,username, date, etc,  would be entered into the next blank row on that journal sheet

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/nmUgzfN.jpg

This picture refers to the general idea of how I want the sheets to work (the above is month 1, the bottom is month 2)

Answer (score 0):

If you're not familiar with VBA, it would be simpler to just use Track Changes.

First, save the workbook as a shared workbook:

1. Go to Review Tab
2. Click Share Workbook
3. Put a tick in the checkbox to allow changes by more than one user at a time
4. Click OK and save the workbook if prompted

All changes are now automatically being logged each time the workbook has been saved. To see all changes at any time:

1. Save workbook
2. Go to the Review Tab
3. Click Track Changes then Highlight Changes
4. Untick "When" to show "All"
5. Untick "Who" to show "Everyone"
6. Untick "Highlight Changes"
7. Tick "List changes on a new sheet"
8. Click OK

[image: TrackChanges]

A new sheet called History will be added showing all changes made every time the workbook was saved.

To see only changes since the last time you saved, change the When box to "Since I Last Saved".

Comment: https://i.imgur.com/nmUgzfN.jpg

So this is how I want the sheet to work... with track changes, if the user makes a change and then re-edits the change, does that force multiple outputs?

Comment: If you're not familiar with VBA, you'll need to hire a programmer. StackOverflow isn't a "Do your project" service. It will help you when you get stuck or have particular questions, but won't create your entire program for you.

Comment: I've updated the answer to address your additional question about track changes.

Comment: Thanks @Michael I am trying to find a way to get Track Changes to work in a user friendly manner.  I think the "Since I Last Saved" box would be the best option here if I opt out of VBA use.
Granted, I do know VBA and might attempt to solve this with that, but I was mostly wondering if there was a basic function or if chain that would solve it more simply.  Either way, a VBA investment might not be worth it if it's too difficult, since the future state of the document will be to directly link the data from the SQL server, removing the need for user inputs or history logging.